# Josh Earnest - Press Secretary or Oxymoron?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, synonyms

Isn't the current Whitehouse press secretary's name, **Josh Earnest**, an example of an oxymoron? Can proper nouns even be oxymorons, and if so, could I (acceptably) refer to such as, *oxymoronic*? Can you conceive of any other colorful terms for a name such as the example?

Comment: I'd go with "Ironic" rather than "Oxymoronic" because "Josh" doesn't contradict "Earnest", though you may believe Josh's *behaviour* does.

Comment: (Is that really the guy's name?) Technically, I think it would have to be "Earnest Josh" to be an oxymoron, but it's still a bit "ironic" for a press secretary.

Comment: So many of his official press releases are ambiguous, too. Is this an example of "life imitating art"?

Comment: To make matters worse (*or better*) there's a rumor going around (*which I am unable to verify*) that his middle name is, "Beauregarde", which would then give us (*I can't help it*), **Josh B. Earnest**!

Comment: @DanBron I think she meant "Josh" in the slang sense of "I'm just joshing you" e.g. "I'm just kidding with you". That definition of the word contradicts Earnest, making it an oxymoronic name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's **incongruous** (out of place, perhaps humorously so) (Google has 'not in harmony or keeping with the surroundings or other aspects of something').

Paradoxes / oxymorons {paradox defined [here at AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/paradox)}

> paradox  n.
>
> 1. A statement that seems to contradict itself but may nonetheless be true: the paradox that standing is more tiring than walking.
> 2. A person, thing, or situation that exhibits inexplicable or contradictory aspects: "The silence of midnight, to speak truly,
>      though apparently a paradox, rung in my ears" (Mary Shelley).
> 3. A statement that is self-contradictory or logically untenable, though based on a valid deduction from acceptable premises.

have to do with apparently contradictory statements or occurrences, not comical adjacencies of words.

Answer (score 3):

***[Inconsistency](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/inconsistency)*** seems like a better description of the relationships between Josh's names:

> Josh (the informal jocular type) is *inconsistent* with Earnest (the
>   intensely serious type)
>
> 1. Not staying the same throughout:

**but** Josh's names seem to describe his routine performance perfectly:

> Informal jocularity deflecting serious intensity toward absurdity!

Oxymoron seems a bit too strong.

Comment: Like "banging a U-ey" at 70 mph.

Comment: I just changed my mind! See edit.

Comment: True, that. And the whole "changing my mind" thing really works here. :-) I'm just looking for permission to call something "oxymoronic"! It's sort of a vicarious titillation thing (I hate to keep using that word as I'm guilty of criticizing others for doing the same ... thing). :-P

Comment: If you want to call Josh a *moron*, just go ahead; it seems to be acceptable political expression, and the *oxy-* prefix just distracts from you true intentions?

Comment: But I'm just not comfortable with that level of honesty. Not really knowing the chap I need to couch my vitriol in (pseudo) erudite terminology.

Comment: To the sofa you go then :)

Answer (score 1):

I would describe Josh Earnest's name as **paradoxical.** ODO defines the relevant sense of [*paradox*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/paradox) as follows:

> 1.2 A situation, person, or thing that combines contradictory features or qualities:
>
> *the mingling of deciduous trees with elements of desert flora forms a fascinating ecological **paradox***

Comment: Wouldn't the term for a fascinating ecological paradox be a _foxymoron_ :-) ? (Indebted to a Cambridge University research team managing to get paid for watching meerkats for this Cooperism).

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't the current Whitehouse press secretary's name, Josh Earnest, an example of an oxymoron?

No.

*Josh* means "Jehovah is salvation". (short for Joshua, from Yehoshua; יהושע).

The meanings of surnames are more difficult to determine but it's quite likely *Earnest* here comes from the same root as the English word *Earnest*. Really though it's not really useful to think of surnames as meaning anything beyond indicating what family someone is from.

In any case, it's highly unlikely that it secretly means "Jehovah is not salvation".

There's no contradiction.

The fact that there is a homonym *josh* that means "to make a joke" makes it a vague *apparent oxymoron*; only vague because it's possible to be earnest while making a joke, and only apparent because it depends upon a completely different words that happen to be a homonym.

> Can proper nouns even be oxymorons,

Yes, if they are composed of two or more words that contradict each other. This would be more likely with a company name than a personal name.

> and if so, could I (acceptably) refer to such as, oxymoronic?

Yes.

Comment: I haven’t checked if any dictionaries have kept up here, but the extended meaning of _oxymoron_ to refer to something that is simply an ironic contradiction only half in terms seems fairly widespread to me. The oxymoron here is of course not meant to be between _Josh_ and _Earnest_, but between being called _Earnest_ and having the (at least facetiously speaking) inherently dishonest job of being press secretary to the White House. Kind of a backwards or ironic aptronym (ineptronym?), if you will.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet that'd be apparent oxymora, though this is only a vague one since there isn't that strong a contradiction between *earnest* and *josh* either.

Comment: josh /jäSH/ informal verbverb: josh; 3rd person present: joshes; past tense: joshed; past participle: joshed; gerund or present participle: joshing

1. tease (someone) in a playful way.
"he loved to josh people"
•engage in joking or playful talk with others.
noun North American
noun: josh 1. good-natured banter. Origin
mid 19th century (as a verb): of unknown origin.

Comment: Thanks @Jon Hanna - the first reply comment was for you but I exceeded my 5-minute time limit (which I didn't know of). My initial google returned this top response (which included an n-gram graphic I don't know how to include - can anyone advise?).

Comment: Do I detect a note sarcasm in your comment, @Janus Bahs Jacquet? Where have all the flowers gone? +1 for the double word-play of "ineptronym"! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Colorful, huh? How about:

"Hey Josh, that's a nice *thumb-your-nose-at-the-American-People* handle you've got there, is it a family name?"

Comment: I know! I mean, are they simply toying with our credulity? It's like an inside (the Whitehouse) joke!

Comment: Then again, I seem to recall that on more than one occasion Larry Speakes (press secretary/administration spokesperson under Ronald Reagan from 1981 to 1987) declined to comment on particular questions from the press. I kept hoping to see a story headlined "Speakes Won't Talk." Maybe irony/paradox/oxymoronhood are natural to the job.

Comment: Or absolutely necessary! +1 @Sven Yargs - I forgot Mr. Speakes, LOL.